# Is installing MONO on an IBM RISC running AIX possible and or practical? And if so where do I start?

Tags: mono, aix

Is installing MONO on an IBM RISC running AIX possible and or practical?
And if so where do I start?

Comment: This seems more suited for superuser.

Answer (score 0):

AIX is not one of Mono's [supported platforms](http://mono-project.com/Supported_Platforms).

From [the FAQ](http://mono-project.com/FAQ%3a_Technical#Portability):

> Mono currently runs on Linux, Windows, Solaris, FreeBSD and MacOS X. The Just-In-Time engine (JIT) is available on x86 and PowerPC, Sparc and S390 processors and can generate code and optimizations tailored for a particular CPU. Interpreters exist for the Itanium, HP-PA, StrongARM CPUs.

You could always download [the source](http://download.mono-project.com/sources/), and compile it yourself, after working out the platform specifics. Namely, the JITter would need to be ported to handle the processor.